# overflow in exponential function while trying to integrate

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, integer-overflow

I want to numerically integrate a discrete dataset (given ad pandas series) -here orange- which is multiplied with a given analytical exponential function (derivative of a Fermi-Dirac-Distribution) -here blue-. However I fail when the exponent becomes large (e.g. for small T) and thus the derivative `fermi_dT(E, mu, T)`explodes. I couldn't find a way to rewrite `fermi_dT(E, mu, T)`in an appropriate way to get it done.

Below is a minimal example (not with pandas series), where I simulated the dataset by a Gaussian.

If T<30. I'll get an overflow. Does anyone see a clever way to get around?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

scale_plot = 1e6
kB = 8.618292134831462e-5 #in eV
Ef = 2.0

def gaussian(E, amp, E0, sig):
    return amp * np.exp(-(E-E0)**2 / sig)

def fermi_dT(E, mu, T):
    return ((np.exp((E - mu) / (kB * T))*(E-mu)) / ((1 + np.exp((E - mu) / (kB * T)))**2*kB*T**2))


T = 100.0
energies = np.arange(1.,3.,0.001)

plt.plot(energies, (energies-Ef)*fermi_dT(energies, Ef, T))
plt.plot(energies, gaussian(energies, 1e-5, 1.8, .01))
plt.plot(energies, gaussian(energies, 1e-5, 1.8, .01)*(energies-Ef)*fermi_dT(energies, Ef, T)*scale_plot)
plt.show()

cum = integrate.cumtrapz(gaussian(energies, 1e-5, 1.8, .01)*(energies-Ef)*fermi_dT(energies, Ef, T), energies)
print(cum[-1])
```

[image: matplotlib output, gaussian orange, derivative of Fermi-Dirac blue and weighted product of both aka the integrand in green]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of numerical issue is quite usual when dealing with exponential derivatives. The trick is to compute first the log, and only after to apply the exponential:

`log(a*exp(b) / (1 + c*exp(d)) ** k) = log(a) + b - k * log(1 + exp(log(c) + d)))`

Now, you need to find a way to compute `log(1 + exp(x))` accurately. Lucky for you, people have done it before, according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20888225/4820605). So maybe you could rewrite `fermi_dT` using `log1p`:

```
import numpy as np

def softplus(x, limit=30):
    val = np.empty_like(x)
    val[x>=limit] = x[x>=limit]
    val[x<limit] = np.log1p(np.exp(x[x<limit]))
    return val

def fermi_dT(E, mu, T):
    a = (E - mu) / (kB * T ** 2)
    b = d = (E - mu) / (kB * T)
    k = 2
    val = np.empty_like(E)
    val[E-mu>=0] = np.exp(np.log(a[E-mu>=0]) + b[E-mu>=0] - k * softplus(d[E-mu>=0]))
    val[E-mu<0] = -np.exp(np.log(-a[E-mu<0]) + b[E-mu<0] - k * softplus(d[E-mu<0]))
    return val
```

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with my formulation. I'm on it.

Comment: That's beautiful! Was trying to rescale or tried to translate exp(x) to exp(-x). But that's neat.

Comment: Are you sure it is working ? It seems wrong. I updated my answer but I'm still not convince...

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9b7ff60faa841f0473facf618cb5b66b9cb99b5e/tensorflow/core/kernels/softplus_op.h#L37) is tensorflow implementation of so-called softplus function `log(1+exp(x))` for reference. And a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230635/avoid-overflow-with-softplus-function-in-python) of this topic.

Comment: FYI: You can also use `np.logaddexp(0, x)` for `log(1 + exp(x))`.

Comment: I fixed the overflow issue, but now the approximation clearly appears in `softplus`. I don't know to what extend it will alter the final result. @WarrenWeckesser Yes, `logaddexp` is basically the generalization of `log1p`.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure whether your first version would’ve worked. I only used the log1p and it worked out for me. I’ll try your exact implementation, too.